# Initializing a union with anonymous structs

Tags: c++, c++11

I am merging together a tree structure into a library.
The library in question has a compile time check prevent users from leaving uninitialized variables while merging, among other checks.
The tree structure I am trying to merge has the a structure like

```
struct TreeNode
{
  int Dimension;
  int ChildIndex;
  union {
    struct
    { 
      float LMax;
      float RMin;
    } Node;
    struct
    {
      int Start;
      int Size;
    } Leaf;
  };

  TreeNode()
    : Dimension()
    , ChildIndex()
  {}
};
```

When I have this class merged, and I compile the library, I get `-Wmissing-field-initializers` warnings for the union which is not initialized by me.

I am looking for a way to initialize the union in the constructor of the `TreeNode`.
Can anyone please point me to how this could be done?
I also seek advice if the TreeNode can be structured in a better way.

Comment: *"I am looking for a way to initialize the union"* Initialize to what state? Anyway, something like `TreeNode() : Dimension(), ChildIndex(), Node{1, 2} {}`

Comment: So this node is used in a lot of places and I know for sure that none of the members are left without a value.
So if the TreeNode is representing a node, then in those cases I have
`Treenode t;
t.Node.LMax = XX;
t.Node.RMin = YY;`
Similarly, I have that for leafs.
My objective is just to get around the `-Wmissing-field-initializers` warnings so that they do not show up on the dashboard
This may be poor S/W Engg practice, but it seems to be the only way around.

Comment: Consider adding a tag `g++`

Comment: What GCC version? I'm not getting any warning. There were a couple of bugs in GCC related to this warning. E.g.: [#36750](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=36750)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from the comment, you want just to suppress the warning. Also, looks like you're using GCC. You can implement this like following:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmissing-field-initializers"

struct TreeNode { ... };

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

The second line suppresses `-Wmissing-field-initializers` warnings in the code after it. Since you don't want to suppress this warning in all code everywhere, you need to save your warnings settings (first line) and restore it later (last line). For further information, consider reading [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.3/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html).